# Can you test Android Apps on a physical Android device using a Mac?

Tags: android, macos

Let's say I have an iMac with Android Studios installed and I would like to use it for Android App Development, could I test the applications I build on a physical device like the Samsung S7? I know with Windows I needed to download a driver for my s7 device in order to get it to show up in Android Studios.. but I'm wondering if it's possible on a Mac. If so how exactly is this done and what additional steps need to be taken?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist thing you will need to do is to set your debuggable property to True in your `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
 }
```

To get your device to show up in android studio on Mac, you should just have to plug it in ( as the Android Documentation says: "It just works") - making sure that developer mode has been selected on your Samsung.

I've been building with Android Studio on my Macbook Air for a couple of years and haven't had any real issues with getting Android Studio to recognise a physical device - any time it hasn't picked it up a good old fashioned reboot of Android studio does the trick! :]